# How to set and access values of nested array objects in React state using useState hook?

Tags: json, reactjs, object, state, use-state

This is my state.

```
const [poll, setPoll] = useState({
    pollQuestion: "Sample question- Is it fine?",
    pollOption: [
      { optionId: 1, optionText: "sample option1", votes: "0" },
      { optionId: 2, optionText: "sample option2", votes: "0" },
      { optionId: 3, optionText: "sample option3", votes: "0" },
      { optionId: 4, optionText: "sample option4", votes: "0" },
    ]
  });
```

I am trying to set optionText for my poll.
I am currently using this, but this is wrong.

```
onChange={(e) => setPoll({ ...poll, pollOption.optionText: e.target.value })}
```

Can someone correct me?

Also how to set the value of the option text box?

```
 value={poll.pollOption.optionText}
```

I tried this, but it sets the value of all 4 input fields simultaneously

Comment: For the first one, which one do you need to change? The entire PollOption?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @Veno There are 4 similar input fields for entering 4 options. I wanted to change the first object in the PollOption[] array in the state when the user types in the 1st option box. 
Similarly there will be 3 more onChange functions for the other 3 input fields

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what is wrong, but at a first glance, PollOption is an array of objects, so you have to specify the index to access the correct object.

To change the OptionText of the object with index `i`, try:

```
onChange={(e) => setPoll({ ...poll, PollOption[i].OptionText: e.target.value })}
```

So changing the object with `OptionId: 4` would mean changing the 4th object in the array, so `i = 3`:

```
onChange={(e) => setPoll({ ...poll, PollOption[3].OptionText: e.target.value })}
```

Comment: What if the OP wanted to change the second option? What about the one with `optionId` 4?

Comment: Edited my answer with a general and a specific example.

Comment: Thanks @wesley.buijsman for answering, but  this doesn't seem to work with useState. 
I tried the functional way of setting state also by passing previousState and returning a new state, but they are not working. I am attaching a link, you can edit the code live and see https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-objects-doubt-rcu0e